# visual studio set all my controls to the same location

Tags: css, visual-studio

the scenario is the next..

i have a style sheet like:

.class{display:block;position:absolute;}

which i assign to every control inside a div. the problem is that after i drag and drop controls into the div, visual studio modify my css class and ends up like:

.class{display:block;position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px}

which results in every control having the same position

is there a way that visual studio set the position individually and not touching my class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a workaround. it consists in specifying any position to each control in the source view before asigning it the css class,after this i can move any control independently from the design view.

Answer (score 0):

The best process is to write the code using the `Source` view and not `Design`.  `Design` is really intended to be used more as a visual reference than as a design surface (though admittedly Microsoft tried, and failed, to make it work for design).